# How can I get my XCUI Test to run on multiple targets in Xcode: "first select a valid Target Application for it in the project editor"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcuitest

I have my Test file inside a UI project which builds and runs successfully, there are other white label projects that are different versions/styling of this one. how do I record tests on the project? Currently if I try I get the following message "To perform UI Recording in {mytestFileName}, first select a valid Target Application for it in the project editor."

Comment: Did you select a target application in the project editor?

Comment: turns out the target was the issue. I moved the test to one of the white labels and selected a target there. Thanks!